# http.delete() not working in Angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

**deleteTask** method is not working in this code. Other methods are working fine. There are no issues with URL. Please help me..

```
constructor(private http:Http) {

    console.log('task service activated');

}

getTasks(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/tasks').map(res => res.json());
}

addTask(newTask){
    console.log(newTask);
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.post('/api/task',JSON.stringify(newTask),{headers:headers}).map(res => res.json());


}

deleteTask(id){

    return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/task/'+id).map(res => res.json());
 }
```

here is back end code

```
router.delete('/task/:id',function(req, res, next){

  db.tasks.remove({__id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id)}, function(err,task){

   if(err){
     res.send(err);
   }

   res.json(task);
 });

});
```

Comment: last thing. one of your other backend routes might help to put in the question too. since you said those are working. i notice your using __id instead of _id which i think is the mongo default. That seems unusual but i doubt its your problem.

Comment: don't use `mongojs` and your _id has typo here try this `({_id: req.params.id}`

Comment: @Ashish Thank you..!!. problem solved. removed additional underscore ( "_id")

Comment: @Matt Pengelly Thank you..!!. problem solved. removed additional underscore ( "_id")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice your using __id instead of _id which i think is the mongo default. Try changing that.